# Bitfinex get Trading Fees via API

Tags: api, bitfinex

After placing a market order, I got its order_id & checked its status via this end point `/v1/order/status` and I got the following:

```
Array
(
[id] => 18141116927
[cid] => 43611135723
[cid_date] => 2018-10-17
[gid] => 
[symbol] => iotusd
[exchange] => bitfinex
[price] => 0.51251
[avg_execution_price] => 0.51234
[side] => sell
[type] => market
[timestamp] => 1539778090.0
[is_live] => 
[is_cancelled] => 
[is_hidden] => 
[oco_order] => 
[was_forced] => 
[original_amount] => 20.0
[remaining_amount] => 0.0
[executed_amount] => 20.0
[src] => api
)
```

In this array, I don't see exchange fees for this order. Also the above order is closing a margin position and I was expecting to see fees associated to margin like borrowing costs etc.

How do I get these information via API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the endpoint where trade fees along with order_id and fee_currency are included `https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/mytrades`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [price] => 0.53018
        [amount] => 20.0
        [timestamp] => 1539786993.0
        [type] => Sell
        [fee_currency] => USD
        [fee_amount] => -0.0212072
        [tid] => 301116948
        [order_id] => 18151111432
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 0.5317
        [amount] => 20.0
        [timestamp] => 1539786941.0
        [type] => Buy
        [fee_currency] => IOT
        [fee_amount] => -0.04
        [tid] => 301116560
        [order_id] => 1815111391
    )
)
```

This endpoint can also accept `limit_trades` parameter to limit the number of results returned. Then use `foreach` loop to get to the required order_id & retrieve the trade fee. Not sure why bitfinex has chosen to make it complicated, this information should be included with the "order status" endpoint.